# maven: what to do if javadoc missing?

Tags: maven, javadoc, maven-central

I run

```
mvn dependency:resolve -Dclassifier=javadoc
```

and report say that

```
[INFO] The following files have NOT been resolved:
```

I know that Maven repositories hosted by volunteer organisations like Maven Central and hosted open source project done by volunteers.

But missing javadoc make me angry as using packages without javadoc is hard (leaving IDE to do web search and read outdated docs).

I report missing javadoc for Hibernate in Central one time (in Hibernate BTS). Without success. For another projects I have no strong intention to find home page and BTS/mail list to report missing javadocs.

What the best way to improve situation?

Comment: For example in hibernate (ex. hibernate-core has a sources packages) so i don't see the problem?

Comment: @khmarbaise IDE able extract docs from source package? NetBeans/Eclipse?

Comment: Just use the source code to see what's going on. JavaDocs usually don't show more information (i know there are some exceptions).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use this command in your project folder:

> mvn dependency:sources

It will download all your dependencies' sources in your maven local repository as a jar archive (jar per dependency).

I use Netbeans 8 and Maven 3, and the IDE automatically recognizes the javadoc.

I'm using right now Hibernate 4.2.3 and the javadoc pops up whitout problem.

Comment: After time of asking that question I learnt that IDEs able to use sources to extract JavaDoc. Also *most of public Maven repositories require uploading of source package among with binary*. So anytime you need JavaDoc - **just use sources**!

Comment: @gavenkoa Thanks! Your solution worked perfectly for hibernate. Just downloaded sources and javadoc automatically started showing up :)

Answer (score 1):

If your using IntelliJ then you can right click pom.xml and click maven -> Download Sources and Documentation